# Iterating to a distinct list and insert values into another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple query:

```
select distinct USERS from [USER_TABLE]
```

It returns something like

```
Thunder Cat
He Man
```

What I want is to iterate over this list and insert it into another table:

```
User 1: Thunder Cat
User 2: He Man
```

I'm trying an apporoach like this:

```
declare @i int = 1;
while (select distinct [USER] from [USER_TABLE]) > 0
begin
    exec dbo.audit_log concat('User ', @i), 'test';
end
```

(where audit_log is a stored procedure to insert lines into a logtable)

This, however, gives me an error: `Incorrect syntax near 'User '.`

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is this the best way to approach this?

Comment: Why not just INSERT the rows straight into the new table? Why do you have to do it row-by-row?

Comment: What @RhysJones said.

But if you really(like REALLY REALLY) need to do that one by one. You'll have to use cursors.

Comment: Or just take code from __dbo.audit_log__ sp and append to use all user table.

Comment: @RhysJones I'd prefer to insert via the SP to keep a consistent workflow / script. In the rest of the script, all status messages that need to go to the audit log, are inserted via the SP. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you run into this situation often, you should consider creating a stored proc to accepts a table (UDT). The current one could simply call that passing the single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to loop through your data set. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
        (
            [Row_Num] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
            [Users] VARCHAR(100)
        );

INSERT INTO @Table
        SELECT DISTINCT [USERS]
        FROM [User_Table]

DECLARE @loopCounter INT = 1,
        @LastRowNum INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table),
        @user VARCHAR(100);

WHILE (@loopCounter <= @LastRowNum)
BEGIN
    SET @user =  (SELECT [Users] FROM @Table WHERE Row_Num = @loopCounter);
    EXEC dbo.audit_log @user,' test';
    SET @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1;
END
```